# GAS - draw line chart using column A as X and column B as Y

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, embedded-resource

In google spreadsheet, I wish to use script to draw a line chart with column A as X and column B as Y.

But below code will draw 2 line. how can I modify it to draw one line just like B = f(A).

```
function myDemoLineChart() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B4")
   Logger.log(range)

   var lineChart = sheet.newChart()
  .setPosition(6, 1, 0, 0)
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .setOption("title", "Demo")
  .setOption("hAxis.title","X")
  .setOption("vAxis.title", "Y")
  .setOption("curveType","function")
  .setOption("pointSize",10)
  .setOption("width",800)
  .setOption("height",800)
  .addRange(range)
  .build()
  sheet.insertChart(lineChart)
}
```

Input data as below:

```
A   B
3   5
1   7
4   2
2   9
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

1. Sort by column "A".
2. Add `setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)` as an option.

#### Modified script:

```
function myDemoLineChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B4")
  Logger.log(range)

  range.sort(1); // Added

  var lineChart = sheet.newChart()
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true) // Added
  .setPosition(6, 1, 0, 0)
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .setOption("title", "Demo")
  .setOption("hAxis.title","X")
  .setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "Y"}}) // Modified
  .setOption("curveType","function")
  .setOption("pointSize",10)
  .setOption("width",800)
  .setOption("height",800)
  .addRange(range)
  .build()
  sheet.insertChart(lineChart)
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)
- [Sample script of useFirstColumnAsDomain](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Great, that's what I want! BTW, why the y axis lable not show?

Comment: @lucky1928 Thank you for replying. I apologize I couldn't notice about the issue. There are several vertical axes. So it is required to use ``setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "Y"}})``. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? And is this information useful for your situation? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4125cc280e15c0fc726cb2fe4f35a3f7